# why the DIV jumps why I scroll window( it works fine in firefox while not in chrome&safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#box').css('top', $(this).scrollTop())
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box"></div>
```

**
when I scroll page,this #box jumpy;maybe you suggest me use position:fixed ,however, The animation need use javascript.
help me, please

Comment: Works fine for me (Chrome). Why does this absolutely need JS? It's easy in CSS.

Comment: This is the nature of scroll based events - I am afraid making this work smoothly in all browsers requires research - I doubt you will get a comprehensive answer to this question as its very broad.

Comment: thank u for your attention. css is easy ,however, javascript is better for my project: have a look 
[link](http://www.sensoro.com/en/yunzi);
sroll the page and look the bottom of sensor,it is jumpy